# Hooking OpenGL Help (4 - 5 Questions)

Tags: c++, opengl

Ok so I've successfully hooked all the OpenGL functions using my own glwrapper. Problems I'm having is when it comes to Intel/Nvidia vs. ATI. I'm hooking models and generating ID's for each model so that I can tell what's rendering.

The below is the information I currently have + the differences:

```
glPushMatrix()

glMultMatrixf({0.70710671, 0, 0.70710683, 0}
{0, 1, 0, 0}
{-0.70710683, 0, 0.70710671, 0}
{26368, -1125, 28416, 1})

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 56)
glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 11544, 0x0B2DF6EC)
glGenBuffersARB(1, 0x0AE6231C)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 65)
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 11544, 0x0B2DF6EC, GL_STATIC_DRAW)   
glGenBuffersARB(1, 0x0AE6231C)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 66)
glBufferDataARB(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 7020, 0x0B2DF6EC, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

//Everything above is done by both graphics cards. Below is where the problem comes in.

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 56)         //Intel/Nvidia makes this NULL.
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 12, 0x00000000) //Intel/NVidia makes this Not 0x00000.
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 65)
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 12, 0x00000000)
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 12, 0x00000004)
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3510, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0x00000000)
```

I want to know why bother NULL-ing the bindbuffer call and not nulling the vertex pointer for Nvidia && Intel cards whereas on ATI, everything is as is above.

What's the difference? Also my second question is, if I stored the pointers to the vertices and the indicies (guaranteed that they will not be deleted), how can I get each vertex?

Example:

```
VBO CurrentBuffer;
std::vector<VBO> Buffers;

Hook_glBufferDataARB(GLenum target, GLsizeiptrARB size, const GLvoid *data, GLenum usage)
{
    CurrentBuffer.target = target;
    CurrentBuffer.size = size;
    CurrentBuffer.usage = usage;     //To figure out if it's indices array or vertex array.
    CurrentBuffer.data = data;       //Let us assume that this pointer is never deleted.

    (*original_BufferDataArb)(target, size, data, usage);
}

Hook_glVertexPointer(GLint size, GLenum type, GLsizei stride, const GLvoid *pointer)
{
    CurrentBuffer.VNull = (pointer == NULL) ? true : false;
    CurrentBuffer.VPointer = pointer;  //This can be both null or not null.
    CurrentBuffer.VSize = size;
    CurrentBuffer.Vtype = type;
    CurrentBuffer.Stride = stride;
    Buffers.push_back(CurrentBuffer);

    (*original_VPointer)(size, type, stride, pointer);
}


void Hook_glDrawElements(GLenum mode, GLsizei count, GLenum type, const GLvoid *indices)
{
    if (mode == GL_TRIANGLES)
    {
        const GLfloat* Pointer = static_cast<const GLfloat*>(Buffers.back().VPointer);  //Assuming it isn't NULL.
        for (int I = 0; I < count / 3; ++I)  //For each triangle.
        {
            int X = *(reinterpret_cast<const GLfloat*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(Pointer)));
            int Y = *(reinterpret_cast<const GLfloat*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(Pointer) + (Buffers.back().Stride)) + 1);
            int Z = *(reinterpret_cast<const GLfloat*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(Pointer) + (2 * Buffers.back().Stride)) + 2);
        }
    }

    (*original_DrawElements)(mode, count, type, indices);
}
```

Am I iterating the pointers properly? Also if vertexpointer is null, is there a way I can use the bufferdata usage to get each vertex? I read that I can do:

```
if (CurrentBuffer.VNull)
{
    GLfloat* IndexPointer = Buffers[Buffers.size()].data;      //Index pointer is GL_Element_Array_Buffer
    GLfloat* VertexPointer = Buffers[Buffers.size() - 1].data; //Vertex pointer is GL_Array_Buffer

    for (int I = 0; I < TriangleCount; ++I)
    {
        int X = *VertexPointer[IndexPointer[I]];
        int Y = *VertexPointer[IndexPointer[I]] + 1;
        int Z = *VertexPointer[IndexPointer[I]] + 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 56)         //Intel/Nvidia makes this NULL.
> glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 12, 0x00000000) //Intel/NVidia makes this Not 0x00000.
> ```

Are you sure, that in your Intel/NVidia case the program is not actively setting those values. A null value as data parameter to glVertexPointer makes only sense if there is a buffer object bound. If however no buffer object is bound, e.g. by unbinding using a glBindBuffer call with the ID 0, then the data parameter to glVertexPointer must be a non-null pointer.

Comment: +1 I didn't think about that and yeah it is setting it. Hmm but why would it do that on intel/nvidia but leave it on ati? That is what I'm not sure about. Either way it's the same thing though right?

What I do not understand is why bother doing that or why set it to 0. Is there a difference?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: Maybe setting it zero is just part of normal operations, you just see it at a different time in program execuation, because being on NVidia or Intel HW triggers a different codepath. Look for the program making a call to `glGetString` – if so, it likely does some alterations to its render paths depending on the HW (quirks, workarounds, etc.). Also be aware that programs may request `glBindBuffer` (w/o the ARB) just as well, if on a version >= OpenGL-2